# python poplib .retr(n) inserting "=", inserting '3D' and splitting objects

Tags: python, poplib

I am using poplib to grab emails from a mail server.  The method retr(n) retrieves the nth email message.  It returns messages in a funny form where everything is broken into lines and placed in a tuple.  What gives! : it inserts the characters '3D' randomly into the email.  Furthermore, it breaks tagged elements into pieces and inserts '=' at the break.  As anyone else seen this?

Comment: That's called "Quoted Printable" encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) the messages are (in all likelihood) already formatted that way.

Comment: neat thanks!  You might want to make that into an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Giving Andrew Medico credit, the string you are seeing is in "Quoted Printable Encoding" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). The emails were already in that format when I received them, in my case.

I was able to turn it back into a "normal" string using the quopri module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html).

```
import poplib
import quopri

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL( "the_host" )
pop_conn.user("my_user")
pop_conn.pass_("my_password")

email_i_want = 1

encoded_msg = pop_conn.retr( email_i_want )[1]
joined_msg = str( '\n'.join(encoded_msg) )
decoded_msg = quopri.decodestring( joined_msg )

print decoded_msg
```